# TravisCI - Fastlane gym can't find my certificates in the keychain

Tags: ios, match, travis-ci, code-signing, fastlane

I am trying to setup TravisCI to build my iOS app. The goal is to use Travis for testing and for deploying beta releases. Actual releases I think I'll do myself.

However, I can't seem to make it work as it gets stuck on this step no matter what I've tried (unless it crashes earlier in the process).

I have removed my team id and my app name, but assume those are correct. Otherwise point out why there'd be a mismatch.

I have so far set these variables in Travis:

```
FASTLANE_PASSWORD = A generated Application Specific Password for my AppleID
MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME = "MatchKeychainName"
MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = can't remember, but it's used by both create_keychain and match
MATCH_PASSWORD = The password for my match repository
```

There is also an SSH key setup in Travis to have access to my repo. When I setup this I had barely even started using my own certificates so I just nuked both appstore and development after running fastlane match init, and then I created new certificates using match for both.

My assumption was that when I run match inside the lane, it will automatically synchronise the certificates from the repo to the keychain that is currently the default of the system (the one I created just before, if you see the Fastfile).

Any aid regarding this is super welcome! I have followed this guide initially: [Build distribution automation with fastlane and Travis CI - iOS](https://medium.com/practo-engineering/build-distribution-automation-with-fastlane-and-travis-ci-ios-f959dff2799f)

Matchfile:

```
git_url "<a link of the format 'git@github.com:user/repo'>"
app_identifier "com.example.App-Name"
type "development"
username "me@example.com"
team_id "ABCDEFGHIJ"
```

Fastfile (only specific lane and before_all & after_all):

```
desc "TravisCI lane for running tests"
lane :travis_test do
  create_keychain(
    name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"],
    password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
    default_keychain: true,
    unlock: true,
    timeout: 3600,
    add_to_search_list: true
  )
  match(
    keychain_password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
    type: "development",
    readonly: true,
    # username: "travis@example.com" (I tried to add another user to iTunes Connect)
  )
  # setup_travis (tried running the setup_travis fastlane action once.)

  cocoapods(clean: true, podfile: "./Podfile")
  gym(
    scheme: "App Name",
    export_method: "development",
  )

  delete_keychain(
    name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"]
  )
  slack(
    message: "'App Name' tests run on TravisCI",
    channel: "#tests",
    success: true,
    payload: {
      "Built Date" => Time.new.to_s,
      "Build by" => "TravisCI"
    },
    default_payloads: [:git_branch, :git_author],
    use_webhook_configured_username_and_icon: false,
    username: "TravisCI - Fastlane"
  )
end
```

With these settings I get this error:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
[07:27:41]: Exit status: 65
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[07:27:41]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[07:27:41]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[07:27:41]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-9.2.app'
[07:27:41]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[07:27:41]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[07:27:41]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: - Manually update the path using
[07:27:41]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[07:27:41]: 
+---------------+-----------------------------+
|              Build environment              |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode-9.2.app |
| gym_version   | 2.75.1                      |
| export_method | development                 |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS11.2.sdk            |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
[07:27:41]: ▸ === BUILD TARGET App Name OF PROJECT App Name WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
[07:27:41]: ▸ Check dependencies
[07:27:41]: ▸ Code Signing Error: No profile for team 'ABCDEFGHIJ' matching 'match AppStore com.example.App-Name' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'ABCDEFGHIJ/match AppStore com.example.App-Name'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
[07:27:41]: ▸ Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[07:27:41]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[07:27:41]:   /Users/travis/Library/Logs/gym/Dungeon Brawl-Dungeon Brawl.log
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: Your `export_method` in gym is defined as `development`
[07:27:41]: which might cause problems when signing your application
[07:27:41]: Are you sure want to build and export for development?
[07:27:41]: Please make sure to define the correct export methods when calling
[07:27:41]: gym in your Fastfile or from the command line
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[07:27:41]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[07:27:41]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[07:27:41]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[07:27:41]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[07:27:41]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[07:27:41]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[07:27:41]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[07:27:41]: 
[07:27:41]: An error occurred while executing the `error` block:
[07:27:41]: undefined method `error_info' for #<FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneBuildFailure:0x00007fed70beb328>
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 Lane Context                                                  |
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                   | ios                                                                      |
| PLATFORM_NAME                      | ios                                                                      |
| LANE_NAME                          | ios travis_test                                                          |
| GIT_REPO_WAS_CLEAN_ON_START        | true                                                                     |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN          | "/Users/travis/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"                      |
| SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE                  | development                                                              |
| MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING | {"com.example.App-Name"=>"match Development com.example.App-Name"}       |
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[07:27:41]: Error building the application - see the log above
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
|               fastlane summary               |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                  | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform        | 0           |
| 2    | ensure_git_status_clean | 0           |
| 3    | create_keychain         | 0           |
| 4    | match                   | 2           |
| 5    | cocoapods               | 34          |
|    | gym                     | 109         |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
[07:27:41]: fastlane finished with errors
[!] Error building the application - see the log above
The command "bundle exec fastlane travis_test" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: I can see that it tries to use the Appstore certificate, but I am trying to use the development one by claiming which type and export_method I use. Or am I doing that wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @GregHilston I am sure I figured it out but I am not sure why. I think it could be that the provisioning profile wasn't pure anymore, or something. That I maybe had added a device and then manually changed the provisioning profile such that match did not have the latest one, or something along those lines. I think I just ran match nuke development in order to fix it

Comment: Interesting. i was hoping to avoid resorting to `match nuke development`. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @GregHilston I found it quite refreshing though to do so haha. But make sure to setup a device list in the repo as well to automatically manage it in the future, if that was the issue for you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on those two points? What do you mean by a device list in the repo and automatically manage?

Comment: @GregHilston Sorry, I was on vacation. I meant that you should implement the device list that is supported by fastlane match, so that you just have to enter new device id's and names into that same list and just run a match lane you setup for fixing the provisioning profiles given the device list. Read about it in the match [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/register_devices/).